# CSS Aligning item to the right

Tags: css

How to position the elements which are even to the right? I've tried `nth-child(even);` and `float: right;` but it's not working.

```css
#container {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1,minmax(0px,1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 60px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
}

.items {
  width: 80%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.items:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can also use margin-left:auto

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `justify-self: end;` on `.items:nth-child(even)`.

```css
#container {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1,minmax(0px,1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 60px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
}

.items {
  width: 80%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.items:nth-child(even) {
  justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `float:right` to `justify-self: end;`

```css
#container {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1,minmax(0px,1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 60px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
}

.items {
  width: 80%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.items:nth-child(even) {
  justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1,minmax(0px,1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 60px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}
```